# SQLITE: Python inserts Gibberish instead of integers

Tags: python, sqlite, casting

I can't seem to find the reason for the following problem:

```
cur_out.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS key2val");
cur_out.execute("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS key2val_value_index");
cur_out.execute("CREATE TABLE key2val(key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val INT)");
cur_out.executemany("INSERT INTO key2val VALUES(?,?)",((key,value[next(iter(dictionary[key]))],) for key in dictionary));
cur_out.execute("CREATE INDEX key2val_value_index on key2val(val)");
con_out.commit();
```

where `value` is a numpy integer array and `dictionary` is a dict pointing to a nonempty set of integers for each key.

```
>>> for tup in ((key,value[next(iter(dictionary[key]))],) for key in dictionary):
>>>     print(tup)
(615063, 10548)
(615980, 0)
(629315, 10627)
(631978, 0)
(642585, 0)
(643574, 0)
(667025, 0)
(152076, 5406)
(393084, 0)
...
```

Then in the database

```
sqlite> select distinct val from key2val limit 10;
```

returns some weird symbols or combinations thereof that cannot be displayed properly in the terminal nor copied into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not gibberish, at least not random gibberish. The problem is that `value` is a numpy array, so its elements are not Python integers but numpy `int32` or `int64` depending on your version (32 or 64 bits).

This is not a known type for the `sqlite3` module, so it just stores the byte representation. For example on my little endian system with a 32 bits Python, 7 it stored as `b'\x07\x00\x00\x00'`. This is explicit if you display the `repr` of the values, but if you just print them, it is hard to guess what happens.

How to fix:

The simplest way IMHO is to explicitely force a conversion to a Python integer type:

```
cur_out.executemany("INSERT INTO key2val VALUES(?,?)",
                    ((key,int(value[next(iter(dictionary[key]))]),) for key in dictionary))
```

Alternatively, you could register an adapter:

```
def npint_adapt(x):
    return int(x)

sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int32, npint_adapt) # or use np.int64 here if using 64 bits...
```

and then directly insert `np.int32` (resp. `np.int64`) types:

```
cur_out.executemany("INSERT INTO key2val VALUES(?,?)",
                    ((key,value[next(iter(dictionary[key]))],) for key in dictionary));
```

Comment: Allright, well this could happen to some other people as well I guess... Should've known but yeah, thanks!

Comment: @RadioControlled: I was once bitten too, so I now remember...